# Resharper 6.0 Templates Editor no longer working

Tags: templates, editor, resharper

Whenever I try to add a new template or edit an existing one, the template editor window is not opened in Visual Studio and nothing happens.

This happens either for live templates, file templates and surround templates.

The export / import functionality works.

Answer (score 3):

It's a knonw issue here: http://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/RSRP-329433.
The cause of this is, usually, a TeamCity plugin installed in the VS. Please try to remove all other JetrBrains addins, run 'Repair' on ReSharper after that and check if it helps.